# How to know when subscripts refer to charges or not

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, notation, formal-charge

My question is very easy. Sometimes to determine to charge of a compound you multiply the charge by the number of ions you have of that element. But sometimes it seems as if you don't do it this way. Example:

- $\ce{Ba(BrO2)NO2} = \ce{Ba^2+ + BrO2^0 + NO2^-}$: Here you multiply the subscript by the charge of 1- in order to balance it
- $\ce{KNaCO3} = \ce{K+ + Na+ CO3^2-} $: here you **don't** multiply the subscript 3 by the charge 2- for it to be balanced.

Could someone please explain the difference? When do you mdo a multiplication and when not?

Comment: The answer to when do you multiply is this: **you don't**. $\ce{BrO2}$ in this compound (if we assume it exists) is charged -1, not 0. You _do_ multiply, however, when the whole thing is in brackets, but that's another story.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, How did you check whether $\ce{BrO2}$ had a charge of -1 ? I thought compounds with an oxygen in their anion always had a charge -2? Or is this only for acids? (I am a beginner in chemistry)

You do a multiplication only when the whole thing is between brackets or there is a coefficient specified?

Comment: You do the multiplication only when the whole thing is in brackets **and** there is a coefficient specified after the closing bracket. Come to think of it, you also do the multiplication when there are no brackets but the "thing" in question is just one atom, like in $\ce{Ca^{2+}Cl^{-}2}$. $\ce{BrO2}$ must be -1 to balance the whole thing, because $\ce{Ba}$ is definitely +2 and $\ce{NO2}$ is certainly not -2. Anions with oxygen in them are pretty diverse; some have the charge of -1, some -2, some -3 and so on.

Comment: @IvanNeretin. Well there you have it "$\ce{NO2}$ is certainly not $-2$". How do you know that? I was quite sure it was the case. 
Concerning the example from calcium and Chlore. You do the multiplication because the anion is composed just of 1 ion $\ce{Cl2^-}$. If it was $\ce{ClO2^-}$ you wouldn't do such a multiplication? (just made up a random example to clarify what you meant, don't even know if it makes sense)

Comment: No, you do the multiplication because the anion is composed of **one** atom $\ce{Cl^{-}}$, and there are **two** of them (two anions). (Also, it is not good to write things like $\ce{Ca^{2+}Cl^{-}2}$ the way I did in the previous comment, for it may be confusing.) As for $\ce{ClO2^{-}}$, it is one anion, so there is no reason to multiply by 2, unless there are two of them, which would look like $\ce{\dots(ClO2)2}$. As for $\ce{NO2}$, well, I just know that there is $\ce{NO2^{-}}$ and there is no $\ce{NO2^{2-}}$. There are also $\ce{NO2+}$ and neutral $\ce{NO2}$, but that's another story.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, a response to these 2 questions will clarify everything: How would you write it if the compound $\ce{ClO2}$ had a charge of -1? How would you write the formula from $\ce{ClO2}$ if only oxygen had a charge of -1? I think this is the issue I am having: the subscript refers only to that one single element (unless it is written between brackets), while the charges usually refers to the whole compound.

Comment: How would I write what? If you want a compound with anion $\ce{ClO2^{-}}$, look at $\ce{KClO2}$; if I'd like to specify the charges, I would write $\ce{K+ClO2^{-}}$. An example of a compound where you'd better multiply the charge by the subscript is $\ce{CaCl2}$. Not sure how to write $\ce{CaCl2}$ _with the charges_ in a non-ambiguous way; probably $\ce{Ca^{2+}(Cl^{-})2}$ would do.